# Error line 1 at position 16 'D_INS_COMPANY.ORDER_BY' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause

Tags: sql, ssas

Given code is select query wth left out join (select...) in SSAS

```
SELECT D_INS_COMPANY.INS_COMPANY_KEY,
  CASE
    WHEN D_INS_COMPANY.INS_COMPANY_DESC = '-3'
    THEN 'NOT_APPLICABLE'
    ELSE D_INS_COMPANY.INS_COMPANY_DESC
  END  AS INS_COMPANY_DESC,
  D_INS_COMPANY.INS_COMPNAY_GROUP_DESC AS INS_COMPANY_GROUP_DESC,
  COALESCE(PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP,INS_COMPNAY_GROUP_DESC)
    AS PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP,
  D_INS_COMPANY.ORDER_BY,
  D_INS_COMPANY.ORDER_BY_GROUP 
FROM D_INS_COMPANY 
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)) AS INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC ,
    MIN( PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP)           AS PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  FROM LKP_INS_CARRIER
  WHERE TRIM(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY 1
  ) LC 
ON (LC.INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC = TRIM(UPPER(D_INS_COMPANY.INS_COMPANY_DESC)));
```

Getting this error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 16
>   'D_INS_COMPANY.ORDER_BY' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause..

Can someone help me out? Thank you

Comment: Just curious = `GROUP BY 1` is neeed?

Comment: I just tried your query in SQL Server 2017 and it runs well. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3f098/1

Comment: I have tried ``(SELECT TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)) AS INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC ,
    MIN( PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP)           AS PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  FROM LKP_INS_CARRIER
  WHERE TRIM(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)),  PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  ) ``       or    ``(SELECT TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)) AS INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC ,
    MIN( PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP)           AS PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  FROM LKP_INS_CARRIER
  WHERE TRIM(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC))
  ) ``   not working

Comment: Thank you for your comment, my company is using version 2010, there is any way I can replace left join (select...)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the below block of code:

```
SELECT TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)) AS INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC ,
    MIN( PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP)           AS PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  FROM LKP_INS_CARRIER
  WHERE TRIM(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY 1
```

There are two issues here. First although you can order by 1 you cannot group by 1. Second is that you are returning two fields and only grouping by one. Any field that is not used in the group by must be an aggregate of some type.

Comment: I think this is not accurate. You can group by the first column, but I think it must be mentioned exactly as it is. See the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have tried this query ``(SELECT TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)) AS INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC ,
    MIN( PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP)           AS PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  FROM LKP_INS_CARRIER
  WHERE TRIM(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC) IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY TRIM(UPPER(INS_COMPANY_SNL_DESC)),  PRIOR_INS_COMPANY_GROUP
  ) ``   , still give same error

Comment: @TheImpaler  Not always, With some version and flavors of SQL the order of operation is such that SQL does not know the field list before the group by. ie SQL 2008 the order of operation is FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER BY so group by 1 will not work.